# How to expire my JWT access_token before its expiry time?

Tags: jwt, access-token, digital-signature

As I have already generating JWT access_token and it expiresIn: 5d,
but I wanted to expire it whenever I am generating the new JWT access_token and want to revoke the last access_token.

How to do this in nodeJs?

Comment: Perhaps this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462856/how-to-expire-a-jwt-token-manually

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: an **access token** should **never** have a lifetime of 5 days.

A JWT is, by design, a *stateless* permission indicator; it says "for the duration of this token, services receiving it should trust the bearer for the purposes listed inside it". This contrasts with a "session token", where the token itself is just a random identifier, and services receiving it need to look it up in some central store to find out what permissions to grant.

The lifetime of a completely stateless access token needs to be as short as practical - normally a few minutes at most. It is essentially a cache lifetime, during which the user's permissions will not be checked against a central store.

Clearly, you don't want to ask the user for their password every few minutes, so you need some token with a longer lifetime. This is where a **refresh token** comes in: a different JWT with a longer lifetime, but *accepted only by an authentication service*. A JWT refesh token says "the bearer of this token completed the login process, and should be authorised to issue access tokens for the user identified".

Unlike the access token, the refresh token is not purely stateless: since it's only accepted by one service, that service can maintain a *revocation list*. When asked to issue an access token, it first checks if the refresh token has been revoked.

That means the refresh token can have a longer lifetime, and also a "rolling" lifetime: when issuing an access token, you can also issue a new refresh token with an extended lifetime. The lifetime represents how long the user can pause between requests and still be logged in.

Note that the revocation likst doesn't need to list all the refresh tokens directly. For instance, if a user logs out, it can record their user ID, and refuse to issue new (short-lived) access tokens for that user. If they log in again, it can record the timestamp, and only accept refresh tokens created after that date.

In summary:

- An access token *authorises* the user (grants them access), and is *stateless by design*. During its lieftime, *it will be unconditionally accepted*, so that lifetime should be *as short as possible*.
- A refresh token *authenticates* (identifies) the user, and is *partially stateful*. Its lifetime is an idle timeout after which the user needs to re-authenticate; within that lifetime, it might be revoked.
- A central service receives refresh tokens, checks them for revocation, and issues short-lived access tokens, plus renewed refresh tokens.
- The actual business services receive only access tokens, which cannot be revoked.

If you don't want the complexity of refresh and access tokens, it's possible that JWT is not the right choice for your application: if you are checking the token on every request, and regularly invalidating it before its expiry date, a random session token with data attached in the application probably makes more sense.